# multi-class order clarification

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing

If a player goes Fighter 1 / Wizard 19, taking the Fighter level first, they get all of the Fighter proficiencies and none of the Wizard proficiencies, correct?  (That is, they get the usual fighter stuff and not the fighter stuff from the multiclass table)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Correct**

You gain all the benefits (skills, weapon proficiencies, armor proficiencies, save proficiencies) from whatever class the PC started level 1 as, then they gain everything else as shown on the multiclass table.